# C++/Boost Insert list items into map without manual loop

Tags: c++, list, boost, dictionary, insert

In a C++ program, I have a std::list and std::map (although I am actually using boost:unordered_map) and I would like to know an elegant way of inserting all the elements in the list into the map. I would like the key to be the result of a method call on the elements on in the list.

So for example I have:

```
std::list<Message> messages = *another list with elements*;
std::map<std::string, Message> message_map;
```

And I want to insert all the elements from the list into the map with the key being message.id(), for every message in messages.

Is there a way to do this without looping over the list and doing it manually? **I can't use C++11** but I would still be interested in C++11 solutions for interests sake. I am able to use boost.

Thank you.

Comment: There will be a loop somewhere unless you unroll one by hand and write a series of `insert`s.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I worded this badly. I mean I don't want to write the loop myself. Sort of like how std::copy and std::inserter work.

Answer (score 3):

A C++11 solution: You can use `std::transform` to transform from `std::list` elements to `std::map` elements:

```
std::transform(message.begin(), messages.end(),
               std::inserter(message_map, message_map.end()),
               [](const Message& m) { return std::make_pair(m.id(), m); });
```

The equivalent can be done with C++03 by passing a function pointer instead of a lambda.

Comment: The OP should note that this is way longer than the corresponding `for` loop, and you need C++11 for this.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if you can you do something similar with Boost? Perhaps using bind?

Comment: I guess there is boost::transform, with more or less (maybe completely) the same syntax. (@sftrabbit Did you forget one .begin() in the inserter?)

Comment: I want to avoid lambdas (can't use C++11).

Comment: Use a functor instead, providing almost the same functionality than lambdas do (but with syntax overhead and some restrictions). Here a  function pointer will also work since you don't have to capture any context variables.

Comment: @rpamely Oh sorry, I thought you said you wanted C++11 solutions. Oops.

Comment: No problem sftrabbit. @leemes a function pointer isn't particularly elegant. I was wondering if you could call make_pair using boost bind so that it's inline.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe boost lambda together with boost transform? I never worked with that, so I don't know how "nice" it looks like if it even was possible.

Comment: @leemes "Did you forget one .begin() in the inserter?" Nope! Yeah it looks odd, but the first argument is the container to insert into and the second is the element to insert in front of.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is better than a for loop but you can use a functor

```
struct map_inserter {
   std::map<string,Message>& t_map;
   map_inserter(std::map<string,Message>& t_map) : t_map(t_map) {}
   void operator()(Message& m) {
       t_map.insert(std::pair<string,Message>(m.get_id(),m));
   }
};
```

You can use it like this

```
std::map<string,Message> t_map;
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), map_inserter(t_map));
```

Answer (score 0):

If u can get iterators to the begining and end of the lis u can use for_each()

Comment: Could this be combined with boost bind and make_pair, so that it's inline?

Comment: Don't use boost wouldn't know, but it will work, you can use a lambda for the function

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Message> MessageMap;

MessageMap& addIdAndMessage(MessageMap& messageMap, const Message& message) {
    messageMap[message.id()] = message;
    return messageMap;
}

int main() {
    std::list<Message> messages;
    //...
    MessageMap message_map =
        accumulate(messages.begin(), message.end(),
                   MessageMap(),
                   addIdAndMessage);
}
```